# Ag grid community version

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Hello can some one help for counting the column data sum to bottom of grid I don’t see the option in the community version but see the option in the enterprise version.

I tried this option but this applicable only for the enterprise version [groupIncludeTotalFooter]="true"